# Get user location and display data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, location

I am creating small React Native app. For backend I will probably go with firebase and mongodb. I will store some restaurants, clubs etc.. I wonder can I get user location and display clubs and restaurants that are nearby. If user denies location permission, Ill go with filter for country and city.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can and here is the API you can do it with: [react-native-geolocation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation) good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this task by

First asking for location permission from the user. You have to use this package. Please go through the example codes first.
[react-native-permissions](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions)

Secondly, you can check for the current location by using these packages. You can also convert the lat/long values to address and vice versa.

```
@react-native-community/geolocation
react-native-geolocation-service
react-native-get-location
react-native-geocoding
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out :)